# stopself() service not working

Tags: android, service

I need to stop the service from itself and I use the `stopSelf` method, but the service is not stopped.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    int hour = MainActivity.sa3a;
    int minute = MainActivity.dakika;
    java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
    int x = date.getHours();
    int y = date.getMinutes();
    String n = String.valueOf(x);
    Toast.makeText(send.this,n, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (hour == x && minute == y) {
        Toast.makeText(send.this, "start", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        send.this.stopSelf();
        Toast.makeText(send.this, "stop_Self_is_Not_work", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(send.this, "yOKKKKKK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think `stopSelf` isn't working?

Comment: Because stop_Self_is_Not_work Toast is shows!! if the stopself work this toast not shows @ Karakuri

Comment: That's not how you check if the service has stopped. The method isn't going to halt on the line `send.this.stopSelf()`, it's going to finish the method, meaning it will show the toast even if the system does stop it. Go find the list of running services in phone settings and see if your service is listed there.

Comment: sorrybut am new in the android ...Do you mean it stopped  ؟ @ Karakuri

Comment: If it's not in the list of running services, then it's not running.

Comment: Even if you see the toast, the service may have been stopped. You need to understand that code execution proceeds to the next line unless the current line is a `return` statement or throws an exception. Even if you call `stopSelf()` on one line, the next line which displays a toast can still run. The system may still be stopping your service and you mistakenly _think_ it hasn't, which is why I am telling you to physically check the list of running services after you see the toast. If your service is not there, then you don't actually have a problem, you can just remove the toast.

Answer (score 1):

In order to see that service is indeed stopping, you need to override the onDestroy() callback. 
Make a toast you want to show in the onDestroy method and then when you call stopSelf() your toast should show.

If the toast in your current condition is not shown, means the condition is not met. If you only call stopSelf from that condition, the service will not be stopped. You need to further review your conditions to guarantee stopping the service where you wish.

Comment: @AbdAljbbarAmmar Did you even attempt to implement `onDestroy()` like this answer suggested?